# Import Excel file into SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to import an Excel file into SQL Server using asp.net. When I click on the link this should bring up a File Open dialog. It should only allow users to select Excel files (`*.xls, *.xlsx`).

I tried to used a boutton when i clicking on this it is calling a method like:

```
protected void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Data Sources (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls*;*.xlsx";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

but it is showing error on `openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Regular Validation Expression to limit the file extensions to your desired types.

```
ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.xls|.XLS|.xlsx|.XLSX)$"
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am not looking for vaildition and i am looking when i click on browse button it should go for check.

Answer (score 0):

SEEN AT: http://forums.asp.net/t/1207019.aspx

Get the extension of the file selected via FileUpload control using the below code.

```
   string Extension = Path.GetExtension(flUpdUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
   /* this will give u the extension*/
```

put a switch case to decide which type u want.

```
    switch (Extension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                    code here;
                    break;

                case ".xlsx":
                    code here;
                    break;
            }
```