# How to import excel file into sql server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I Need to import excel file into Sql server, i have tried by using Fileupload but the fileuploader acccepting all file types, is there any chance to restrict only selected types when we click on browse?

Comment: Please check this post it's the same issue you have:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164324/import-excel-file-into-sql-server

Comment: Possibe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164324/import-excel-file-into-sql-server

Comment: Yes.. I am seriously looking for solution.

Comment: The question in your title does not match the body of your question.  Change one of them -- make them match -- and your question could no longer be unclear... but it could still be seen as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be using AjaxFileUploader:

In Markup:

```
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"                           OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"  OnClientUploadError="uploadError"  
onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" AllowedFileTypes="xls,xlsx"
        MaximumNumberOfFiles="1"/>
```

For more info : [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.aspx)

Comment: Even though he didn't mark this as answer, it looks like he might be using your answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174373/how-to-upgrade-to-new-version-of-ajax-toolkit-with-an-existing-project

Comment: lol it's ok, I hope someone else could benefit from this :)

Answer (score 0):

Extract file extension from filename and check.

```
string Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileUploadControlId.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Comment: My intention is when i click on browse(fileupload) it opens a file open dialog this dialog should allow only excel files.For this i am looking.

Answer (score 0):

use regex to validate file types

```
var regex = new Regex(@".*\.xlsx?$");
```