# How to upgrade to new version of Ajax toolkit with an existing project?

Tags: ajax

Is there any best way to upgrade to new version of Ajaxtoolkit with an existing project?

Answer (score 0):

There's great documentation on how to install the Ajax ToolKit using a new project, but I can't find documentation to upgrade an existing project that uses an old version of the toolkit to a new version of the Ajax toolkit.

I tried it on my own, and now I'm getting Javascript errors all over.  One includes that I need ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts.  In debug, when I'm stepping through code, it's asking me for source code at C:\AjaxBuild\Ajax\Server\AjaxToolkit\ModalPopupExtender\ModalPopupExtender.cs.

Here's what I did:

1.) Deleted folders (ar - zh-CHT) from the bin directory

2.) Deleted AjaxControlToolKit.dll & AjaxControlToolKit.pdb from the bin directory

3.) Removed the Ajax Control Toolkit from my tool bar in VS

4.) Deleted the reference to AjaxControlToolKit in my project references

5.) Copied files from AjaxControlToolKit\WebForms\Release into my bin folder in my project

6.) Added references to the new AjaxControlToolKit and System.Web.Ajax dlls (from my 
project's bin folder).
7.) Added the Ajax Library to my Toolbar in Visual Studio (2008)

8.) Replaced my script managers with the new one from the Ajax Library toolbar

9.) Updated my Web.config file with the new bindingRedirect:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.30512.20315" newVersion="3.0.31106.0"/>
```